# How can i use class Tailwind using Props on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

i've tried to using reusable component on vue js like pass props class name. In my case, i'm using tailwind css, how can i pass class name using props. Thanks guys, Have nice weekend :)

this is my html **router tag**

```
router-link.button-filled(
 :to="routeName"
 :title="title"
 :class="customClass"
)
 | {{ title }}
```

this is my **props**

```
props: {
  routeName: { default: "/", type: String },
  title: { default: "Button", type: String },
  size: { default: "md", type: String },
  backgroundColor: { default: "red-500", type: String },
  borderColor: { default: "red-500", type: String }
},
```

this is my **computed**

```
computed: {
  customClass() {
    return [
      "fst-bg-" + this.backgroundColor,
      "fst-border-" + this.borderColor
    ];
  }
}
```

[image: this class was loaded but style not applied]

Comment: Check out "Dynamic Values" in the Just-in-Time Mode (Tailwind CSS version v2.1+) - link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support - which advises "Arbitrary values cannot be computed from dynamic values." Also, all CSS must be purgeable b/c PurgeCSS "doesn’t try to parse your HTML and look for class attributes or dynamically execute your JavaScript — it simply looks for any strings in the entire file that match this regular expression" (source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

how's good? 
Do you really need this 'fst' prefix?

If so, you'll need to configure this fst as a prefix in the *tailwind.config.js* file, to do so you can check this part of the doc: 
[#Tailwind prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix)

But If you want to use custom colors instead you'd want to checkout this part of doc: 
[#Tailwind custom colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)

Comment: Hi @felipemm Good Thanks!. I was config on tailwind.config.js files .. thats works as well.. but not works on props one.. i've tried to add these 'fst' prefix in computed return but not work, any solution for props? Thanks :)

Comment: That's very strange, it should be working as expected. 
Have you tried using directly fst-bg-red-500 ?
Or instead of using computed, using something like a method or a variable that you sets on mounted/created lifecycle? Might help us understand this behavior